# Can't create Material Icon vector asset

Tags: android, vector, frontend

I'm an android developer and I'm having several problems trying to create a vector asset from the Material icons. 
These are my steps:

1. Right click in the drawable folder and select "New"..."Vector Asset"
2. Choose an option from Material Icon and without changing anything.."Next", "Finish".
3. The error "RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory '/sensicity_android'" is shown in my Event Log and no image is created in my "drawable" folder.

If anyone can help me it will be fantastic...thanks for reading.